# How to find a position, knowing a direction, angle and distance?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image]

Using the diagram provided, I know:

- Character at position A, facing B (posA)
- Object at position B (posB), facing a random direction.
- desired angle (20) for C (desiredAngle), based in the direction A to B.
- distance from B to C

How would I go about finding the position of C?

In the code below, I managed to get the vector BC, now how can define a point along that vector using the distance from A to B?

```
//The angle of the hand in relation to the object
public float angleFromPlayer = -60f;

//Get the direction vector from the selectedObject to the actor
Vector3 objectDirectionToActor = actorParent.position - selectedObjectCenter;

//Make it horizontal (Flatten the y)
objectDirectionToActor.y = 0;

//Get the rotated vector using the desiredAngle
Vector3 rotatedVector = Quaternion.Euler(0, angleFromPlayer, 0) * objectDirectionToActor;
```

Comment: Isn't this a mathematics question? Basically: use `Atan` to get the angle of line BA relative to 0. Add/subtract the desired angle, and use `Sin` and `Cos` with the angle and length BC to calculate the position of C (don't forget to add position B to the result). And don't forget that C#'s `Math` deals in radians, not degrees.

Comment: @Castor where does `Vector3` come from? What is `Mathf`?

Comment: @John Mathf are the [Math functions from Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.html). I'm looking for the result in 3D space, but ignoring the Y for now. posA and posB are both Vector3. (I also know these are probably very basic trigonometry questions)

Comment: It looks like you're using degrees  instead of desiredAngle since degrees  is never specified.

Comment: @John my bad, I renamed the variables for clarity and missed that one by mistake. Fixed now.

Comment: @Castor I don't really get what you're trying to do, but if you want to get something perpendicular to the current angle, then just add 90 degrees to the original angle and do the offset all over again.

Comment: @Castor I think I get what you're trying to do,  you want B's angle between A and C. To get the angles TO and object, use atan2 using the difference between A and then the difference between C to get their angles, then just subtract them from each other to get the delta.

Comment: @John Sorry for the lack of clarity. The goal is to figure out where C should be knowing all the other variables. So I already know the angle I want, the distance from B to C, and that A is always facing B. What I was trying to do was using the formula above, but rather than using the default direction of the world  (which is what happens with that function), start the angle using the direction from B to A.

Comment: @Castor that's what I and the other John are advising you use Atan2 for. It will allow you to find the angle between BA and the world. From there, you can calculate the angle with desiredAngle relative to the world.

Comment: @John(s) Thank you for the guidance. Unfortunately I have no idea how to do that. Still figuring out what Atan2 even does. I have rudimentary knowledge of trigonometry. (Right now googling what Atan2 is and how to use it with Vector3, since Atan2 asks for 2 floats)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/conorbuck/2606166 here you go

Comment: @John(s) Thank you for the link, that was clear. So I understand that Atan2 gives me the angle between 2 directions. But I only have one direction AB, I don't know where C is.

Comment: Atan2 gives you the angle between two points. x and y. Once you get the angle from B to C and from B to A, you can just subtract one from the other to get the difference.

Comment: @John(s) How can 2 points have an angle? I assumed an angle would require 2 directions, or 3 points at least? Is it in relation to a ground axis? (so sorry if this is obvious) Also how can I get the angle from B to C if I don't know where C is?

Comment: @John(s) Thank you for your time and patience, I really appreciate it. I'll look at other resources to learn the answer to this question.

Comment: @John(s) I've updated the question with what I figured out so far. I was able to get the vector BC, now all I need is to get a point along that vector at the distance of 0.1f

Comment: Get the direction by subtracting the two points, then dividing the resulting delta by the hypotenuse. That will give you the normalized direction. Then you can simply multiply it by whatever distance you want such as 0.1f and add it onto the starting point which would be B.

Comment: @John(s) Thank you once again for the guidance and patience. I've got it working and added the full code to the OP.

Comment: Do note that it's allowed and encouraged to post your solution as an actual answer. So feel free to removed it from the question, put it into an answer, and even accept it.

Comment: @Bart Thank you for letting me know. I removed the answer from the original question and added it below as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, here is the solution for posterity:

```
//How high the hand will be from the dropSurface/selectedObjectPivot
public float handOffsetFromDropSurface = 0.15f;

//The angle of the hand in relation to the object
public float targetAngleFromPlayer = -80f;

//Extra distance between selectedObjectCenter and wristBone (since the handDistance is a bit too short)
public float extraHandDistance = 0f;

Vector3 GetHandBonePositionForDropSurface(Vector3 selectedObjectCenter) {
    //Get the direction vector from the selectedObject to the actor
    Vector3 objectDirectionToActor = actorParent.position - selectedObjectCenter;

    //Make it horizontal (Flatten the y)
    objectDirectionToActor.y = 0;

    //Change vector size to 1 for multiplication
    objectDirectionToActor.Normalize();

    //Get the rotated vector using the desiredAngle
    Vector3 rotatedVector = Quaternion.Euler(0, targetAngleFromPlayer, 0) * objectDirectionToActor;

    //Get the distance we want the point to be from the center of the selectedObject
    float handDistance = 
    Vector3.Distance(playerProperties.boneRightIndexProximal.position, 
    playerProperties.boneRightHand.position) + extraHandDistance;

    //Resize vector to match the hand distance
    rotatedVector *= handDistance;

    //Get finalPosition, adding the handOffsetFromDropSurface
    Vector3 wristTargetPosition = selectedObjectCenter + rotatedVector + (Vector3.up * handOffsetFromDropSurface);

    return wristTargetPosition;
}
```